# RestKit - delete an object based on incoming attribute

Tags: core-data, restkit

I am using basic RestKit mapping with JSON I am receiving via a REST call.

```
 RKManagedObjectMapping* contactMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Contact class]];
[contactMapping mapAttributes:@"id", @"firstName", @"middleName", @"lastName", @"title", @"email", nil];
contactMapping.primaryKeyAttribute = @"id";

[contactMapping mapRelationship:@"addresses" withMapping:addressMapping];
[contactMapping mapRelationship:@"phoneNumbers" withMapping:phoneMapping];

// Register our mappings with the provider
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:contactMapping forKeyPath:@"contacts"];
```

I have a new field, status, which I now need to check to see if it's "Delete" (or whatever) and if it is, delete that contact from the database, if they exist. However I'm at a loss as to where to put this. Do I need to create my own extended Object Mapping class to handle this? Are there any examples anywhere of this? My Google Fu is weak on this one.

Comment: i think this kind of functionality should be placed in your `didReceivedObjects` delegate method. Simply iterate over received objects and delete those matching your req.